# How to generate the .jks file with the DocuSign generated Public key & private key

Tags: java, docusignapi, jks

I have public key & private key with me. These keys are generated by the DocuSign backend itself. Now I need to generate the `.jks` file out of it to use in my application. I only have a public key & a private key. I don't have any certificate provided by DocuSign. I tried a lot using commands like:

1. `openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -days 1000 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout kmat_wmio.key -out kmat_wmio.crt`      (generates private and public key pair)
2. `openssl pkcs12 -export -in kmat_wmio.crt -inkey kmat_wmio.key -out kmat_wmio.p12`   (Keystore in PKCS12 format)
3. `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore kmat_wmio.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore kmat_wmio.jks -deststoretype JKS`  (Keystore in JKS format)

But these commands didn't help much. They generate the new public & private key. But I need to generate the `.jks` file with the existing public & private key. Please suggest the suitable guideline or correct commands for the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Now i need to generate the .jks file out of it, to use in my
> application.

I'm not clear why you need this. The private key is used for JWT Authentication and is a text file format. You don't need another file, you can use it as-is with Java to make API calls using JWT.
I would suggest you use the [Java package](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.docusign/docusign-esign-java) (SDK) that has built-in wrappers that just take the private key and a few other pieces of information and get you an access token to make API calls.

Easier still would be to download the [Java quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) which includes all the code you need to make eSign API calls with DocuSign using Java.

Comment: Did OP mention about the JWT?

Comment: no harry, but it's called conjecture. The only reason to generate these keys in DocuSign is for use with JWT authentication.